# Tree looks different on Cmd than it does on Powershell

Tags: powershell, cmd, powershell-ise

Why does the tree command look different on Powershell than what it does on Cmd.

[image: Powershell vs cmd tree command]

Comment: Try another font. Consolas for example.

Comment: use the `/a` option to use text chars instead of graphics chars. the reason is that the PoSh console does not support the same character set unless you find a way to tell it to do so ... and i can't find any way to do that at this time.

Comment: PS is using ANSI or Unicode and CMD using OEM (aka DOS)

Comment: @Olaf It's a character-encoding problem, so choosing a different font won't help.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Note that the problem only affects the ISE; setting `[Console]::OutputEncoding` to the OEM code page fixes it; see my answer for details.

Comment: @Mark When decoding output from external programs, PowerShell does honor the active OEM - except in the ISE, where the ANSI code page is used by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The **problem only occurs in the PowerShell *ISE***, where output from external programs such as `tree.com` *isn't* passed straight through to the console.

  - Consider migrating away from the PowerShell ISE, given that it is [no longer actively developed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/ise/introducing-the-windows-powershell-ise#support) and [there are reasons not to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/45375) (bottom section), notably the inability to run PowerShell [Core] 6+, where all future effort will go. The editor that offers the best PowerShell development experience, across platforms, is [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/), combined with its [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell), which is under active development.
- To fix it, **you must (temporarily) change `[Console]::OutputEncoding` to match your system's active OEM legacy code page**, because that is the character encoding `tree.com` uses:

```
# Switch the encoding that PowerShell expects external programs to use
# to the active OEM code page.
[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(
  [cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture.TextInfo.OEMCodePage
)

# tree.com now produces the expected output in the ISE
tree
```

---

Note:

- **Even in a regular console window / Windows Terminal window and in Visual Studio Code `[Console]::OutputEncoding` *can* come into play, but only when you *capture or redirect* an external program's output** (e.g., `$treeOutput = tree` or `tree | ...`).

  - As indicated above, this is *not* necessary for direct-to-display output - except in the ISE, where `[Console]::OutputEncoding` matters even then, which default to the system's active *ANSI* legacy code page.
- For PowerShell to correctly interpret an external program's output when capturing or redirecting it, **`[Console]::OutputEncoding` must match the actual encoding used by that program**.

**Therefore, if you want to *capture or redirect* `tree.com`s output, you *may* have to set `[Console]::OutputEncoding`**:

In short, unless `[Console]::OutputEncoding.CodePage` matches the code-page number reported by `[cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture.TextInfo.OEMCodePage` - e.g., `437` on US-English systems - setting `[Console]::OutputEncoding` *is* needed.

- In **console windows** and **Windows Terminal windows** this is generally *not* necessary (as of PowerShell 7.0) -  it is only necessary if you've explicitly changed the active code page to UTF-8, for instance - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/45375); note that UTF-8 may become the default over time.
- In **Visual Studio Code**, however, it *is* necessary by default, because in the PowerShell Integrated Console `[Console]::OutputEncoding` defaults to UTF-8 (code page `65001`).

Answer (score -1):

I believe it's because it's one of those commands that PowerShell runs cmd for in the background then pipes the output to **Write-Host**, similar to **ping** or **ipconfig**

Comment: `tree.com` is an external executable, which PowerShell invokes directly - no involvement of `cmd.exe`. In console windows and Visual Studio Code's PowerShell Integrated Terminal, output from external programs is _passed through_ to the console (unless captured or redirected). In the ISE, by contrast, the output is first internally captured and decoded, and then printed to the display (though I doubt that actual `Write-Host` calls are involved).